# Perl: Given a text file, I have to save in a matrix only the lines of text that contain a certain word

Tags: file, perl, split

I'm using a script that saves an html page to a text file.
Inside this text file I have several lines.
I would like to save some of these in a matrix (2 x n) that I will use in the future to fill a postgres table.

the file has many repetitions of these 4 lines:

```
ExitNode 0011BD2485AD45D984EC4159C88FC066E5E3300E
Published 2019-11-09 02:20:53
LastStatus 2019-11-09 03:02:54
ExitAddress 162.247.74.201 2019-11-09 03:03:21
```

I would like to save in the matrix, the Ip and date for each ExitAddress that I find in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'file.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my @ip;
my @date;
while( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    if  ($line =~ /ExitAddress\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/) {
        push @ip, $1;
        push @date, $2;
    }
}
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understood your problem correctly but anyway my solution will look like following

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

my @data;

while( <DATA> ) {
    if( $_ =~ /ExitAddress\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/ ) {
        my($ip,$date,$time) = ($1,$2,$3);
        printf "IP: %15s DATE: %10s TIME: %8s\n", 
                     $ip, $date, $time if $debug;
        push @data , [$ip,$date,$time];
    }
}

print Dumper(\@data) if $debug;

foreach my $e (@data) {
    printf "%15s %10s %8s\n", @{$e};
}

__DATA__
ExitNode 0011BD2485AD45D984EC4159C88FC066E5E3300E
Published 2019-11-09 02:20:53
LastStatus 2019-11-09 03:02:54
ExitAddress 162.247.74.201 2019-11-09 03:03:21

ExitNode 0011BD2485AD45D984EC4159C87FC066E5E6F01A
Published 2019-11-09 03:40:12
LastStatus 2019-11-09 04:7:48
ExitAddress 162.247.74.167 2019-11-09 04:08:03
```